# I'm afraid that my players are losing interest in the game due to my amateur GM ability

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, new-gm

I have recently started running a game for a group of new players, but as this is the first time as the GM, my skill set is still a bit lacking.

Over the past few games, I created a little bit of a story line - introduced a villain, and a plot hook, and created the environment in which the players established themselves; a small town. However, a lot of the detail was lost (due to poor management/note-taking), one player dropping out, and a hap-hazard side quest to fill in time. So I have decided to go for a "new slate" situation.

In our last game, on the way back from their side quest, the players came back to town to find it completely destroyed. I tied it in with the plot points I had established before, and "saved" a few of the NPC's that the players had made friends with. It was basically a massive railroad to get them out of town, and move on to the next one, to re-establish the scene. For the most part, I thought it went ok, but at the end of the game, the players voiced their discontent with the situation.

A specific example of this; when the players were met with the destroyed town, instead of "Oh no's!", the players groaned or made comments like "All of our hard work has been for nothing!" They then proceeded to search the town, perhaps trying to redeem the situation, but as I mentioned, I wanted to re-create the setting, so all investigation turned up very little. After a few rounds of this, the group finally threw up their hands and accepted the inevitable, grumbling about "lost progress".

As the GM, what tactics/skills do I need to employ to stop this 'new slate' situation from happening again?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the discontent they voiced? What were their specific concerns/complaints? You say you're worried they're losing interest; tell us what makes you fear that.

Comment: Putting on hold to workshop.  Per above comment please expand on what they are unhappy about - if it's 'we have the sads because something bad happened' it's not really you at fault...

Comment: Did they say they are losing interest in the game?  Your subject seems largely unrelated to the text of your question.  What investment are they sad about losing - just time getting to know people?  Or did they invest financially somehow in building the town?  Being "new" is also being a bit of a red herring and as you can see answerers are tempted to just offer random new-GM advice, which is fine but not really fitting our Q&A format.  Flesh out the specific issue you're having (with your players' point of view, ideally) and what you'd like to happen instead and we can help.

Comment: I don't understand your players' reaction.  "All of our hard work has been for nothing!" and "lost progress" is almost the opposite of what I'd expect like "who did this?" and "how do we find those responsible and exact revenge" or something like that.  Was that second kind of reaction also present at the table during their search and questioning of the survivors?  Throwing hands up and whining isn't an adventurer's way. What's the story?  Is who destroyed the town and how the town got destroyed an integral part of the story that is connected to how you are moving in a new direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**May I recommend [this archive](https://roleplayingtips.com/archives/) of general DM tips and tools?**

Its archives of newsletters answering common DM troubles and proposing creative solutions. It was my bible when I first started out.

I feel like a lot of the trouble you are having is a lack of world-building and prep. Yes, randomly generated or loosely defined adventures CAN be fun - but I don't really recommend this for new DMs, as it can get difficult to keep track of and hard to focus.

#### Running a Module

You may want to consider running a module to get a feel for how you should lay out and structure your next custom adventure. This will help you hone your DMing skills and also have a structure to help keep the players on track. Modules will normally give you tips and alternatives if the players aren't following the direct path.

For 5e, there are tons of free modules for any system on Drive Thru RPG. As a starting DM, I would recommend doing adventures for characters levels 4 or lower as it often more simplistic in the beginning to have less stats, immunities, etc. to worry about.

There is also the starting adventure from the 5e starter box, *The Lost Mines of Phandelver* and its sequels you can buy at most book stores.

There is also the *Adventures League* available from Wizards of the Coast, that you can buy in [bundles of Seasons](http://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=45470_0_45463_0_0_0_0_0) that have short pre-made adventures that are all loosely connected.

#### Alternatives to Railroading

It can be frustrating when your players are not going towards the adventure, and barring a module to help guide them, the more attractive solution is to just force them through environment or DM Fiat.

Instead of doing this, let players wander off and do what they want. Say you make a dungeon to the north of town but they go south... Well, looks like the dungeon was in the south all along!

Be flexible with when and where plot hooks crop up, or locations are. Have back-up plot hooks and side-quests you can use if they wander off the beaten path or blatantly ignore the story objective. Side Quests can be just as fun and entertaining to do, and if they like it enough, maybe you can morph the story to be more centered on the side quest they enjoyed rather than your main plot line.

As an RPG, the players have agency over what they do in the world first and foremost. If they are not having fun and are purposefully avoiding your plot, *ask them what kind of quest they WOULD like*, or what kind of action they'd like to see.

You may be surprised at their creativity!

Comment: The edit I made to the headings was in line with [this meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6498/23970); if you feel like those weren't really structural headers in your original post please feel free to roll back my change: click on "edited XX ago" and you'll see a listing of all the revisions to this question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still getting used to the formatting here, and I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about the players not picking up your plot hooks, try writing them in such a way that the exact location of your dungeon / ambush / whatever is not precisely defined ahead of time.  That way, you can plop it down in front of them whichever way they choose to go exploring.  Have a few options ready and use the ones that seem to garner favourable reactions.  Drop the ones that don't go over so well.

I don't usually spend too much time statting up monsters that are just going to die anyway - I save that for the Big Bads and recurring NPCs.  I'm also not shy about killing a monster that technically still had 10 HP left, or causing the remaining goblins to rout, if I get the feeling like a fight is going on too long.  As DM, you have the authority to fudge any die rolls and bend any rules if they aren't working out for the group - use it wisely.

Also, try to encourage your players to talk amongst themselves when the party is quiet, and listen to what they're saying.  What do they think is coming up around the next bend?  What do they think the villain's big evil plot is?  What would be a cool side quest or experiment they'd like to try?

Whatever they talk about, take (point-form) notes and use those ideas to build future encounters and side quests in between sessions.  Twist things up with your own imagination so that they aren't running in to everything exactly like they said it last week.  You'd be surprised how little you need to change before this becomes "your" idea.

If it feels like the group is losing interest or frustrated about something, don't be shy about asking them what it is.  You're all there to have fun together, so you want to make sure you're running a game that everyone (including yourself) wants to be a part of.

Comment: I'm not sure what paragraph 3 has to do with OP's question--or are you just suggesting it as a general "good GMing" practice?

Comment: A lot of this advice is good, even great (I'm especially fond of the last paragraph). That first paragraph, though, is deeply troubling. People are often silent because they're uncomfortable, and taking silence for assent is not cool. It's also encouraging GMs to *not* ask for advice on how to improve play experiences which are simply acceptable--so the experience doesn't rise above "not awful enough to actually complain."

Comment: @BESW -- furthermore, people may stay silent because *they don't have the tools to express what they're thinking*, which can be a real nasty pickle to get out of...

Comment: @BESW Actually, my point in the first paragraph is that you *should not* take silence for consent.  If you aren't sure whether or not you're railroading the group too much, you should push them until they complain so that you know where the boundaries are for the group.  This is intended to *encourage* discussion between the GM and the group about what kind of game they want to play.

Comment: There are much better ways to encourage discussion than being deliberately provactive until your friends can't stand it. If that's not what you intended to convey, please [edit] your answer to be more clear.

Comment: Clearly, that part of the answer is not being received the way I intended it.  I can't think of a better way to phrase the idea, though, so I just removed it.  Thank you for the feedback.